# Apigee Emulator on Mac M1

Tags: apigee

Does anybody know how to run Apigee Emulator version > 1.6.1 on Mac M1?

I can run 1.6.1 version but any other newer version doesn't work.

- In the image bellow, the 1.6.1 is stopped, but it works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX3ju.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebg5x.png)